# referring to an embedded excel worksheet in powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I searched in the net and found some similar cases, but they couldn't help me much.

I have an embeded Excel Worksheet in Powerpoint. I want to automatically save the Powerpoint Presentation as a PDF file, using a button.The name of the PDF file should include a number from a particular cell in the Excel Worksheet. I added a button (on the menu taskbar) with a macro, that automaticaly saves the Powerpoint as a PDF. Do you know, how can I refer to the cell in the Excel Worksheet in order to  use it for the name of the PDF?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this gets the first cell in first table in first slide

```
    Debug.Print Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

Comment: Hey, jsotola, thanks for the answer but I already solved the issue. I used 

`ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Sheets(1).Range("C3")`

Since it was an embeded OLEF Format.